# Azure access same VNet from two different subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-security

we have two subscriptions, A and B. A has a VPN and VNet to talk to on-premises resources, how could we access that VNet from subscription B? We would like to set it up on an app service so we can also talk to on-prem.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no way to access the same VNet from two different subscriptions. But we can use [virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) to connect networks from two different subscriptions. So you can create a networkB in subscription B, then you can use virtual network peering to connect B network to A network.

Reference:

[Create a virtual network peering - Resource Manager, different subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions)