# Share a VNet across subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Does Azure have the ability to share a VNet between different subscriptions ?

GCP has a [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) feature in which a VPC defined in projectA can be used by other projects.

Im aware of VNet peering but thats multiple VNets. Im looking for something in Azure in which I can define VNetA in subscriptionA and have resources that are part of subscriptionB deploy resources in VNetA.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to deploy the resources that are part of `subscription B` deploy resources in VNetA(`Subscription A`). But we can use [***virtual network peering***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-deployment-models-subscriptions) between to connect network  from two different subscription under same Azure Active Directory tenant.

Or you can move networking resource in another subscription,This [***article***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/networking-move-limitations) describes how to move virtual networks and other networking resources to a new resource group or Azure subscription.

You can also refer this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348083/azure-access-same-vnet-from-two-different-subscriptions) had someday also asked same requiremet but sadly is there is no as of now.